# Batch Converting XML Documents with Style Sheet?

Tags: xml, xslt

Fairly Novice developer here and new to this forum, but thank you all very much in advance.

So I have a folder with Thousands of XML Documents in it that I need to convert into human readable format.  These XML documents also have a style-sheet (XSLT) that I would need to reference while processing to get the output document into human readable format, preferably PDF, but html or some other file format may work as well.

Now I can go through and open the XML documents one by one into Edge, and then reload to Internet Explorer mode before printing to PDF, but with Thousands of files this is not feasible.

I am very familiar with Robocopy, Xcopy, and creating batch scripts as well as I have some a command line program that will convert the XML documents to PDF however in doing so it does not stylize the outputed PDF leaving a lot of white space and the document very unreadable.

My question what is the best and quickest way to convert these XML documents into something human readable utilizing the referenced stylesheet?

Now I can go through and open the XML documents one by one into Edge, and then reload to Internet Explorer mode before printing to PDF, but with Thousands of files this is not feasible.